# Problems with Git adding folders on a case-insensitive file system

Tags: windows, git

I´m testing Git on Windows to consider using it or not.
I´ve just started a new repository, created a `.gitignore` file and tried to add some folders.

By now, I´ve faced two problems:

1. I´ve created the `.gitignore` file using the `touch .gitignore` command, after that, I´ve tried to add the filters with a `cat .gitignore` command, but it doesn´t seem to let me add anything, I have to edit the file manually.
2. For the test, let´s suppose that I have a folfer named as "Folder", if I use the command `git add folder`, git seems to add it correctly but if I check it with a `git status` command, no files have been added, so I have to write it case sensitive, `git add Folder` and then the `git status` shows the files of the folder tracked.

I´m using Windows and the `gitignorecase` is set to true.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
I´ve search a bit about Git with Windows, and the main opinion normally is "Don´t use Git with Windows", so i will look for other DVCS like Mercurial or Bazaar.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What version of git are you using?  This smells like a bug in Git.

Comment: Or it could be that because Git is case-sensitive at the core, it's refusing to add the files because the case is not correct.  IIRC, `core.ignorecase` was more about tracked files having their case clobbered and still having Git track them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add files to .gitignore, just open it up with a text editor and add them in.  If you wanted to add them in from the output of a unix command, you could do something like `command >> ~/.gitignore`.  This causes the output of command to be appended to .gitignore.

To answer your second question, core.ignorecase means:

> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT. For example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when git expects "Makefile", git will assume it is really the same file, and continue to remember it as "Makefile".  [git-config(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

This definition does not suggest that you can "add" files with the wrong case and expect it to work.  In particular you said "add this directory" and the directory-name you gave was not a real directory (differed by case), so it did nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ok, maybe i can´t add files with wrong case, but the point is that if the file was not really added, Git should output an error message or something like that, not that just telling nothing, like if everything were fine.... It´s my opinion...

Comment: I think that this case falls into an odd part of the functionality.  Since git will tell you if you try to add something that is not a file/directory, but in this case it IS a directory (on that filesystem), but it isn't the correct case-sensitive path for the file.  So there is no error since you tried to add a directory that existed.  I think git's usability could be improved here.

Comment: @MorgoZ, if you consider this behaviour problematic, you might want to bring this issue up on the [main Git mailing list](https://gist.github.com/tfnico/4441562).

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is empty, then nothing will be added as git does not handle empty folders

Answer (score 0):

1. `cat FILENAME` makes `cat` pipe the contents of a file `FILENAME` to its standard output, so in this form of invocation, `cat` cannot be used to *modify* a file.

   If you want to use `cat` to modify the `.gitignore` file, do

   ```
   cat >.gitignore
   ```

   to *overwrite* that file with whatever you will type to the `cat`'s standard input (terminating it by entering `^Z` (`Ctrl-Z`) on Windows) or

   ```
   cat >>.gitignore
   ```

   to append whatever you type into running `cat` to that file.

   In either case, I'd say trying to use a tool this sharp for a task this simple is a bit odd as you appear to display lack of deep knowledge of the standard Unix toolbox. I'd stick to a text editor for now, while learning.
2. I wonder what `gitignorecase` is. The configuration option you need is named `core.ignorecase` and should be set using a command like

   ```
   git config --add [--local] core.ignorecase true
   ```

   Here's the [manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) describing `git config` and all the standard options it knows. You can get the local copy of this manual opened in your browser by running

   ```
   git help config
   ```